# adding multiple function together new to python

Tags: python, function, syntax

so i encountered this question while i was in the tutorial on python at codeacademy
code goes like this

```
def hotel_cost(days):
    return days*140

Charlotte = "Charlotte"
Tampa = "Tampa"
Pittsburgh = "Pittsburgh"
LosAngeles = "Los Angeles"


def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == Charlotte:
        return 183
    elif city == Tampa:
        return 220
    elif city == Pittsburgh:
        return 222
    elif city ==LosAngeles:
        return 475
    else:
        return "not"

def rental_car_cost(days):
    if days <3:
       return days*40
    if days >=3 and days<7:
       return days*40-20
    if days >=7:
        return days*40-50

def trip_cost(city,days):
    return hotel_cost(days)+rental_car_cost(days)+plane_ride_cost(city)
```

again i do aware the mistakes in the syntax of

```
def trip_cost(city,days):
    return hotel_cost(days)+rental_car_cost(days)+plane_ride_cost(city)
```

but i do not have the sufficient knowledge to amend it in any possible way( i did try )

a big thanks to all who take a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy-pasted your code, and everything works well, but there is no output.

So is this nothing showing up makes you think your code is wrong?

simply add this line at the end:

```
print trip_cost('Tampa', 10)
```

and you will see the output

and you can write a bunch of `print`s and `raw_input`s to ask a user input a city and day.

**EDIT**

Oh, I didn't notice the wrong default return of `plane_ride_cost(city)`, simply change it to `0` or something else makes sense when your user inputs a wrong city.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 34, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 31, in trip_cost
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in hotel_cost
NameError: global name 'nights' is not defined

Comment: it gives me this kind of erro :( can you look more into it    thanks for the effort by the way

Comment: how do i use the raw_input in elaboration with the code above i can't seem to make it work like this?                                       nights = raw_input("enter:")
print hotel_cost(raw_iput)

Comment: You use `raw_input()` to get a value from user input, and then you pass it to your functions. Please see documentation here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Comment: it is the value that i m not able to access for instance  i added  a=raw_input("-")


print hotel_cost(a)      it gives me a duplicate version of the number i typed in     i read the link you gave me and didn't find it very helpful to me :(  please inculcate me :)

Comment: I think this will be another question:) the answer is the value you get by `raw_input()` is a `string` and doing the `*` operation to `strings` simply repeats it, you should pass `int(a, 10)` as your `hotel_cost()`'s param.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem within the below function. You return **not** instead of returning an integer. You then try to add the return value within you **trip_cost** method. This won't work right. Consider returning a **0** instead of **not** and then things should work

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == Charlotte:
        return 183
    elif city == Tampa:
        return 220
    elif city == Pittsburgh:
        return 222
    elif city ==LosAngeles:
        return 475
    else:
        return "not"
```